# get a value at firebase database and save it in a variable : android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i wanna make an application for reservation. and i need to cacth some data in other node, then store it in a variable and insert it with a new data input at other node. this is my data stucture that i want :

```
{
"laundry_category" : {
  "laundry_category1" : {
      "name" : "clean laundry",
      "description" : "xxxxxxx"
  }
},

"laundry" : {
  "laundry_category1" : {
      "laundry_id_1" : {
        "name" : "ABC",
        "colour" : "red",
        "description" : "xxxxx"
    }
 }
}
```

for example, i want to get data description form laundry_category node and insert it to node laundry. is it possible?
i have try it in my code but it doesnt work. this is my addLaundry.java code :

addLaundry.java

```
DatabaseReference databaseLaundry;
DatabaseReference databaseCategory;

List<Laundry> laundryList;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseLaundry.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            laundryList.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Laundry laundry = postSnapshot.getValue(Laundry.class);
                laundryList.add(laundry);
            }



            LaundryList adapter = new LaundryList(TambahLaundryActivity.this, laundryList);
            listViewLaundry.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_laundry);


    btAddLaundry = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bn_add_laundry);
    listViewLaundry = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewLaundryLis);

    laundryList = new ArrayList<>();


    Intent intentAddLaundry = getIntent();

    String id_category = intentAddLaundry.getStringExtra(MainActivity.category_id);
    String description_category = intentTambahLaundry.getStringExtra(MainActivity.category_description);

    databaseLaundry = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("laundry").child(id_category);

    databaseLaundry = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("laundry").child(description_category);

    btAddLaundry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addLaundry();
        }
    });


}

public void addLaundry() {
    databaseLaundry.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                category a = postSnapshot.getValue(category.class);
                String var_category_description = ((Map)a).get("category_description").toString();

                String id = databaseLaundry.push().getKey(); 
                Laundry laundry = new Laundry(id, name_laundry, var_category_description); 
                databaseLaundry.child(id).setValue(laundry); 
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
  }
}
```

Laundry.java

```
public class Laundry {
  private String laundry_id;
  private String laundry_nama;
  private String laundry_alamat;
  private String kategori_nama;

public Laundry() {

}

public Laundry(String laundry_id, String laundry_name, String category_description {
    this.laundry_id = laundry_id;
    this.laundry_nama = laundry_nama;
    this.category_description = category_description;
}

public String getLaundry_id() {
    return laundry_id;
}

public String getLaundry_name() {
    return laundry_name;
}

public String getLaundry_alamat() {
    return laundry_alamat;
}

public String getCategory_description() {
    return category_description;
  }
}
```

category.java

```
public class Category {
private String category_id;
private String category_name;
private String category_description;

public Category() {

}

public Category(String category_id, String category_name, category_description) {
    this.category_id = category_id;
    this.category_name = category_name;
    this.category_description = category_description;

}

public String getcategory_id() {
    return category_id;
}

public String getcategory_name() {
    return category_name;
}

public String getcategory_description() {
    return category_description;
}
```

Thankyou so much for your help :)

Comment: You initialize `databaseLaundry` twice, which seems like a mistake. But note that in general Stack Overflow is a lousy substitute for a debugger. It's easiest to help if you isolate the problem into a single snippet of code without external dependencies, so for example with a hardcoded string instead of a `description_category` that you read from user input. Such an isolated snippet is known as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and is the easiest way for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the same data in more than one location, when you upload data, you need to do the same thing twince, on every `DatabaseReference` object. So in order to achieve this, please use this two references:

```
DatabaseReference idCateoryRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("laundry").child(id_category);
```

and

```
DatabaseReference descriptionCategoryRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("laundry").child(description_category);
```

The mistake in your code is that you initialize the same `DatabaseReference` twice. You need to have different `DatabaseReference` for each operation, as mentioned above.

Hope it helps.